# how can i edit this layout in magento 2.4.3

Tags: javascript, php, magento, frontend, magento2

```
{{layout handle="sales_email_order_items" order_id=$order_id area="frontend"}
```

> I want to remove this line form email confirmation but I don't know where this html located.
> [image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

- From handle="sales_email_order_items"

> {{layout handle="sales_email_order_items" order_id=$order_id
> area="frontend"}

- you'll see this layout "sales_email_order_items"

> ```
> <block class="Magento\Sales\Block\Order\Email\Items" name="items" template="Magento_Sales::email/items.phtml" cacheable="false">
> <block class="Magento\Sales\Block\Order\Totals" name="order_totals" template="Magento_Sales::order/totals.phtml">
> </block>
> ```

Maybe, you'll find it in file

> vendor/magento/module-sales/view/frontend/templates/email/items.phtml

or

> vendor/magento/module-sales/view/frontend/templates/order/items.phtml

have a nice day !!